# Github Action tmate - This check was cancelled

Tags: github-actions

I've already attempted to ask about this [on the repo itself](https://github.com/mxschmitt/action-tmate/issues/83) with no luck so far.

I've created a fairly simple workflow based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63009069/2379279) to retrieve a forgotten secret:

```yaml
name: Show Me the S3cr3tz
on: [push]

jobs:
  debug:
    name: Debug
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up secret file
        env:
          MY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
        run: |
          echo $MY_SECRET >> secrets.txt

      - name: Run tmate
        uses: mxschmitt/action-tmate@v3
```

However, I can never see the tmate link because it is cancelled automatically and immediately after leaving the queue:

[image: This check was cancelled]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, if your secret contains special characters, it might undergo parameter expansion – use `printf '%s\n' "$MY_SECRET"` instead of `echo $MY_SECRET`.

Comment: This seems like a GitHub Actions issue, not an issue with your syntax. I just tested your exact code in my repo and I get a tmate session just fine. Have you tried running it more than once?

Comment: @DannyB I wouldn't have posted here if I hadn't tried it more than once. That's why there's a "#5" next to the name of the workflow in that screenshot. However, you are absolutely correct; Github Actions must have been having some hiccups that day because it's now working perfectly. I don't think there's any way I can retract the question, so feel free to write an answer stating that Github Actions was having a bad day and I'll choose it as the correct answer. Otherwise, I'll just create a quick answer myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably related to the [recent GitHub Actions outage](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/m16jzl31gnqt).

The workflow YAML syntax is valid, and confirmed to be working.