# Calling Sftp with Expect fails inside a GitHub Workflow but works locally

Tags: bash, github-actions, sftp, expect, chmod

I have a bash function that's called during a GitHub Workflow run. I'm using Sftp to change permissions on a bunch of remote files — without shell access Sftp is the only way available to me to change the permission using CHMOD.

When I run it in a Docker container with a specific version of Ubuntu and Expect — it runs perfectly. However, with the same OS environment and Expect — it fails in a GitHub Workflow.

### The script `build-tool.sh`

```bash
ftp_put () {
    local   FILE_PERM=${1} \
            FILE_PATH=${2} \
            FTP_HOST=${3} \
            FTP_USER=${4} \
            FTP_PWD=${5}

    printf "\n Setting %s permissions for %s ...\n" "$FILE_PERM" "$FILE_PATH"

    # Connect to the FTP server over 
    expect << EOF 
        spawn sftp -v $FTP_USER@$FTP_HOST
        expect "*yes/no*" {
            set timeout 30
            send -- "yes\r";
            exp_continue
        }
        expect "*?assword:*" { 
            set timeout 30
            send -- "$FTP_PWD\r"
        }
        expect "Permission denied, please try again." {
            exit 1;
            exp_continue
        }        
        expect "sftp>*" { 
            send -- "cd $FILE_PATH\r"
        }
        expect "sftp>*" {
            send -- "chmod $FILE_PERM .\r"
        }
        expect "sftp>*" { 
            set timeout 60
            send -- "quit\n"
        }
        expect eof
EOF
}

...
```

Note: SFTP is being called with the verbose `-v` option, which gets passed to SSH.

### Running locally (Docker container)

Locally, the script is called using remote FTP details which are stored in environment variables.

```bash
. ./build-tool.sh
ftp_put "$FILE_PERM" "$FILE_PATH" "$FTP_HOST" "$FTP_USER" "$FTP_PWD"
```

##### Output log

✅ The script successfully works, and applies the required file permissions:

```
 Setting 555 permissions for app/sprinkles ...
spawn sftp -v mywebsite.com@ssh.mywebsite.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ssh.mywebsite.com [46.30.211.80] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OneSSH-Proxy_1
debug1: compat_banner: no match: OneSSH-Proxy_1
debug1: Authenticating to ssh.mywebsite.com:22 as 'mywebsite.com'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:8sBBlU4Q4RqUzZO1J0RpAucj6/DicaJI1TjPDcRO22U
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'ssh.mywebsite.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mywebsite.com@ssh.mywebsite.com's password:
Authenticated to ssh.mywebsite.com ([46.30.211.80]:22) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: Using server download size 261120
debug1: Using server upload size 261120
debug1: Server handle limit 1048571; using 64
Connected to ssh.mywebsite.com.
sftp> cd app/sprinkles
sftp> chmod 555 .
Changing mode on /customers/a/e/9/mywebsite.com/httpd.www/app/sprinkles/.
sftp> quit
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2516, received 2236 bytes, in 29.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 85.6, received 76.0
debug1: Exit status -1
```

### Running in a GitHub Workflow

In GitHub, the workflow uses remote FTP server details which are stored in GitHub secrets. Other parts of the workflow use the values in these secrets — therefore the issue here isn't with the FTP password being incorrect.

##### Workflow step

```bash
    - name: "FTP:  Add write permissions"
      run: |
        . ./build-tool.sh
        ftp_put \
          755 \
          app/sprinkles \
          ${{ secrets.FTP_PROD_SERVER }} \
          ${{ secrets.FTP_PROD_USERNAME }} \
          ${{ secrets.FTP_PROD_PASSWORD }}

...
```

##### Output log

Note: I've tried putting the secrets in double quotes, and also to call `ftp_put` in a single line, without success.

❌ The script fails with:

```
spawn sftp -v ***@***
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to *** [***] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/runner/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OneSSH-Proxy_1
debug1: compat_banner: no match: OneSSH-Proxy_1
debug1: Authenticating to ***:22 as '***'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:8sBBlU4Q4RqUzZO1J0RpAucj6/DicaJI1TjPDcRO22U
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host '*** (***)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:8sBBlU4Q4RqUzZO1J0RpAucj6/DicaJI1TjPDcRO22U.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
debug1: SELinux support disabled
Warning: Permanently added '***' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/runner/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
***@***'s password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
Permission denied, please try again.
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: try with `expect -d` which outputs more debug info.

Comment: Make sure that secrets have no extra white space and use single quotes for `${{...}}`.

Comment: Also, in your multiline workflow, two trailing slashes are missing.

Comment: @Azeem thanks for noticing, that's a typo and not part of the actual workflow

Comment: Everything else checks out apart from being able to echo the full command with the secrets visible. It's the only thing I haven't done and didn't think is possible, but it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003669/how-can-i-see-my-git-secrets-unencrypted

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881741/7670262.

Comment: Note that `spawn` connects stdout and stderr of the command together, so the `expect "*?assword:*"` will match the debug1 msg. The timing before sending the password can be critical due to pty echo off and flush. Try adding a `sleep 2` before the send to see if this is the problem.

Comment: @meuh It's true that `spawn` creates a process whose stdin, stdout and stderr are connected to Expect, but the debug to stdout doesn't interfere with that at all, so it's unrelated to this problem, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After echo'ing the GitHub secrets to the workflow output, with e.g. `echo ${{ secrets.FTP_PROD_PASSWORD }} | sed 's/./& /g'`, I found that the FTP account that I'm using in the rest of the workflow is using regular non-encrypted FTP (Port 21), whereas the SFTP from my Docker container is using a SSH/SFTP login (Port 22). Problem solved! In hindsight, a simple mix-up.

Works perfectly.

```
 Setting 755 permissions for app/sprinkles ...
spawn sftp ***@***

The authenticity of host '*** (***)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:**********/********.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '***' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

***@***'s password: 
Connected to ***.
sftp> cd app/sprinkles
sftp> chmod 755 .
Changing mode on /customers/a/e/9/***/httpd.www/app/sprinkles/.
sftp> quit

 Setting 755 permissions for app/vendor ...
spawn sftp ***@***

***@***'s password: 
Connected to ***.
sftp> cd app/vendor
sftp> chmod 755 .
Changing mode on /customers/a/e/9/***/httpd.www/app/vendor/.
sftp> quit

...
```