# Github Actions env var not working with .NET GetEnvironmentVariable()

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, github-actions, integration-testing

I want to run Integration test for my .NET API in my GitHub Actions CI/CD pipeline.

I'm using an API Key to authorize access to the API and I retrieve this value using user-secrets on my local machine and everything works fine.

This is the method I use inside my code:

```
public isKeyValid(userApiKey)
{
    apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("X-API_Key") ?? string.Empty;

    return userApiKey == apiKey;
}
```

This is how I set the API Key as env var in GitHub Actions

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env: 
      X-API_Key: ${{ secrets.X_API_KEY }}
```

but my app logs tell that the header does not contain X-API_Key.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried using a different method in .NET like

```
_configuration.GetValue<string>("X-API_Key");
```

but it didn't work.

Echoing secrets in GitHub actions produces ***  for security reasons.

I double-checked naming and possibly typos.

****Solved****
While I was editing my question I realized I was focusing on the wrong line of code. This is how I set up my header in integration test:

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API_Key",Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApiKey"));
```

So, instead of getting the value from env var I was trying to get the header name.

All I had to do was to change to this

```
 env: 
  ApiKey: ${{ secrets.X_API_KEY }}
```

Comment: You can use `sed` to print secrets. See this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881741/7670262).

Comment: If the value is there, try using `_` instead of `-` in the variable name. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821201/7670262).