How to print the sensitive information in workflow log when debug script?
I am debugging the GitHub workflow YAML and want to print some variables, which got via some commands, so that I can double check the values, but when I try to echo the variables the output is *** in the workflow log.
Is there any approach to print the sensitive information in workflow log?

Sounds like you want to print secrets. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881741/7670262.

Thanks. And  sorry for failed find the right key workds in stackoverflow.
echo ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}} | sed 's/./& /g',which will  displays secret key with space between each character.

An idear come from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881741/7670262
    run: |
        echo ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}} | sed 's/./& /g'

Run this action in GitHub and check its console. It displays secret key with space between each character.
